# How to prevent Bootstrap Modal from opening when element inside trigger is clicked?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I've set all rows of my table to open a bootstrap modal.
However, inside each row I have a select box with a couple of status that the user must be able to chose.
How can I prevent the modal of opening when the select box is clicked?

Here is my code:

**HTML**

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-6">
        <table class="table">
            <tr>
                <th>Name</th>
                <th>Status</th>
            </tr>
            <tr class="user-row" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">
                <td>John Doe</td>
                <td>
                    <select class="form-control status-selection">
                        <option></option>
                        <option>Active</option>
                        <option>Inactive</option>
                    </select>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr class="user-row" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">
                <td>Jane Doe</td>
                <td>
                    <select class="form-control status-selection">
                        <option></option>
                        <option>Active</option>
                        <option>Inactive</option>
                    </select>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </div>
</div>

<!-- Modal -->
<div class="modal fade" id="myModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel">
    <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
                <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">Modal title</h4>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
                ...
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Jsfiddle link:
https://jsfiddle.net/2c21mzfm/

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

See [this](https://jsfiddle.net/b8zg57mx/) fiddle:

```
$(".user-row select").on("click", function (e) {
    e.stopPropagation();
});
```

The idea is that you stop the click event (`e` - the first argument of the *on* callback  that is the delegated parameter to the *event*) bubbling up to `.user-row` with [stopPropagation](https://api.jquery.com/event.stoppropagation/)

Comment: Perfect! Solves the problem. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

You are setting the entire table row to activate the modal.  Only set the **td** to activate the modal.

**HTML**

```
<tr class="user-row">
  <td data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">John Doe</td>
  <td>
    <select class="form-control status-selection">
      <option></option>
      <option>Active</option>
      <option>Inactive</option>
    </select>
  </td>
</tr>
```

Comment: I think the questioner would have been aware that they may able to apply the toggle on another element

Comment: guess i didn't assume that.

Comment: I assume it only because they're asking how to prevent the click through. So they know it must be a child of the row. So I assume they didn't want to compromise on clickable area by delegating to any particular cell.

Comment: @Jonathan.. you are right. Thats precisely the case.

Comment: @Howie-.. I have more columns on my real code, . Thanks anyway :)